# How to start second action after check that first one is done in bge?

Tags: game-engine, properties

Here I want help of you people. here I want to start second action animation but before this i want to check that first action is done. same this way i want to do third action before that i want to check first and second action animation complete.

i don`t know how to do this. may be with messages or with properties.

This is same like that man, who has not stick to throw, so first get the stick and then check first stick is in hand or not. If yes then second throw.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Actuator Sensor to measure when an actuator gets activated.

To measure deactivation you invert the sensor output with a negating controller such as NAND, NOR.

[image]

You can read it that way:

```
WHEN "started" -> "play turning"
WHEN "not turned" - is not -> "play lifting"
```

You can even add more animations. Just ensure you have one ActionActuator for each of it.

[image]

I hope it helps