# How can I loop two different animations with one playing right after the other?

Tags: animation, game-engine

I am trying to loop two different animations in my game, one right after the other. In this case I am trying to have SlimeJump1 play, then SlimeJump2 play, then have them continuously play in this order. I have already tried delay sensors, and they won't work. How would I do this? The download link for the file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4IVtcF-FA0dT1ZRV2taajItanM/view?usp=sharing). Thank you!!!

Comment: Sorry for being such a noob, I'm sure there's a simple way to do this. :P

Comment: Feel free to experiment with the file as much as you want.

Comment: You could use the State feature to put the character into a new state after the first jump, which signals the second jump to act. I'm a noob too so that's about all I can offer at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so to do this, you have to have two states. On the first one, you have an always sensor playing the first animation. Then you have a delay sensor that is set for 3 * length of animation - 50 hooked up to a state actuator that changes the state. The second state is the same, but you play the second animation.[image: State 1]
[image: State 2]

Comment: I agree on the state machine. This allows to describe the sequence of actions. But using delay sensors makes you setup animation information (when the action ends) twice. Better use action actuators. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50732/how-to-start-second-action-after-check-that-first-one-is-done-in-bge/51008#51008