# Action Animate Visibility in BGE

Tags: animation, game-engine

Is it possible to animate a given object's visibility inside an Action in Blender Game Engine?

I've been trying to make it by animating the "Invisible" button in the physics tab (it enables the Restrict Render property in the Dopesheet). Every other animation plays as it should within it's Action, but the visibility won't.

Answer (score 0):

The "Restrict Render" setting only applies to the Cycles or BI renderer, but not the OpenGL renderer (used in the viewport, and for the Game Engine).

If you want to achieve something similar, animate the "Visible" attribute instead.

[image: Animate the eye instead of the camera]

Note that this is a binary state. There's no way to fade, or gradually shift from visible to invisible. It will be totally visible one frame, and totally invisible the next frame.

If you're wanting to fade, you'll need to animate the Alpha channel instead (though there is some benefit to turning "Visibility" off, once something is totally transparent).

Comment: still, no good. animating the visibility in viewport yield the same results :/

Answer (score 0):

## Static

- material option (Material tab/Game Settings Panel/Invisible flag)
- physics option (Physics tab/Physics panel/Invisible button)

## Dynamic

- Visibility Actuator

## Semi-transparency

(inefficient on invisible or opaque objects)

- needs texture
- needs material with

  - Material/Game Settings/Alpha Blend: Alpha Blend or Alpha Sort
  - Material/Transparency: enabled
  - Material/Transparency/Z-Transparency
  - Material/Transparency/Alpha: 0.0 .. 1.0 (can be keyframed)

Comment: coincidentally, the object I was trying to animate already had had transparency and alpha texture (kind of a hologram) which make the Material solution very messy (still haven't figured out how to handle it).

Comment: still, my current workaround is scaling the object down to 0 in all axis and bringing up to 1 in the following frame (to avoid interpolation)

Comment: Fading: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?261926; Have you tried the visibility actuator?

Comment: the problem is that i need to animate the visibility in a given part in the middle of an action (like, i need to make it visible at around frame 10 of the action)

Comment: So it is part of an "atomic animation", or is it part of a sequence (e.g. move + turn + hide + move + show + turn)

Comment: it's a sequence. I could upload the file if it helps, but I couldn't find a way to do it in stackexchange.

Comment: This might help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50732/how-to-start-second-action-after-check-that-first-one-is-done-in-bge - it would allow you to play an action -> hide -> delay -> show -> play another action ...